# Saving blobs with Google Endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

I have an app that allows users to save blobs in the blobstore. I have a schema that does so presently, but I am interested in something simpler and less twisted. For context, imagine my app allows users to upload the picture of an animal with a paragraph describing what the animal is doing.

**Present schema**

1. User calls my endpoint api to save the `paragraph` and `name` of the animal in entity `Animal`. **Note:** The `Animal` entity actually has 4 fields ( `name`, `paragraph`, `BlobKey`, and `blobServingUrl` as String). But the endpoint api only allows saving of the two mentioned.
2. Within the endpoint method, on app-engine side, after saving `name` and `paragraph` I make the following call to generate a blob serving url, which my endpoint method returns to the caller

   @ApiMethod(name = "saveAnimalData", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
       public String saveAnimalData(AnimalData request) throws Exception {
   ...
   BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
           String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");
   return url;
   }
3. On the android side, I use a normal http call to send the byte[] of the image to the blobstore. I use apache `DefaultHttpClient()`. **Note:** the blobstore, after saving the image, calls my app-engine server with the blob key and serving url
4. I read the response from the blobstore (blobstore called my callback url) using a normal java servlet, i.e. `public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException`. From the servlet, I put the  `BlobKey` and `blobServingUrl` into the `Animal` entity for the associated animal. (I had passed some meta data to the blobstore, which I use as markers to identify the associated animal entity).

**Desired Schema**

This is where your response comes in. Essential, I would like to eliminate the java servlet and have my entire api restricted to google cloud endpoint. So my question is: how would I use my endpoint to execute steps 3 and 4?

So the idea would be to send the image bytes to the endpoint method `saveAnimalData` at the same time that I am sending the `paragraph` and `name` data. And then within the endpoint method, send the image to the blobstore and then persist the `BlobKey` and `blobServingUrl` in my entity `Animal`.

Your response must be in java. Thanks.

Comment: hey! I use the same process that you but I have one issue. in my success_path servlet, the method getUploads(req) return an empty object.. so I don't have any blobket or blobServingUrl. You know what's wrong?? thx

Answer (score 1):

I see two questions in one here :

1. Can Google Cloud Endpoints handle multipart files ? -> *I don't know about this TBH*
2. Is there a simpler process to store blobs than using the [`BlobStoreService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService)?

It depends on the size of your image. If you limit your users to < 1MB files, you could just store your image as a `Blob` property of your `Animal` entity. It would allow you to bypass the `BlobStoreService` plumbering. See : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities?hl=FR

This solution still depends on how the Cloud Endpoint would handle the multipart file as a raw `byte[]`...

We encountered the same issue with GWT + Google App Engine in 2009, and it was before the BlobStoreService was made available.

GWT RPC and Cloud Endpoints interfaces share some similarities, and for us it was not possible. We had to create a plain HTTP Servlet, and use a Streaming Multipart file resolver beacause the one from Apache's HTTP Commons used the file system.