# getting blobstore to callback to endpoint method

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

I am developing an app-engine connected android project using the eclipse plugin. When I upload an image to the blobstore, how do I make it callback an endpoint method? I find great posts here that can be used as reference to understand my question better (if you need to).

[using blobstore with google cloud endpoint and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246734/using-blobstore-with-google-cloud-endpoint-and-android)

[Saving blobs with Google Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153910/saving-blobs-with-google-endpoint)

So really, I want to know how to make the callback url an endpoint method such as `saveAnimalData` below (I stole from referenced link)

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveAnimalData", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
        public String saveAnimalData(AnimalData request) throws Exception {
}
```

Comment: Hey! Did you ever figure out how to do this?

I have the same issue, want the callback to target one of my endpoint methods

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

https://appid.appspot.com/_ah/api/apiname/version/saveAnimalData

As your final destination url when calling. `blobstoreService.createUrl(destination)` .

Just bear in mind that the request here is not your original submission. GAE will first call an internal URL (the one created by the blobstoreservice), store the blob and then call your destination URL so whatever info you send will be lost before reaching your endpoint (eg AnimalData will be null)